# Scheduling a IEnumerable periodically with .NET reactive extensions

Tags: system.reactive, enumerable

Say for example I have an enumerable

```
dim e = Enumerable.Range(0, 1024)
```

I'd like to be able to do

```
dim o = e.ToObservable(Timespan.FromSeconds(1))
```

So that the observable would generate values every second 
until the enumerable is exhausted. I can't figure a simple way to
do this.

Comment: Can you describe the high-level scenario that you want to accomplish? Either you're misunderstanding Rx, or you want to do something rather strange...

Comment: Simulating a UDP connection for testing purposes. I have an generator as an IEnumerable generating byte frames and I wish to simulate them arriving in real time rather than as fast as possible. The rest of my application will run as normal with the network mocked out by the generator. The UI updates itself as packets are recieved so to check the behaviour without the real source I need to generate data in pseudo real time.

Comment: Have you looked at TestScheduler and friends? This allows you to *simulate* timelines - the code will give the same result as if there are delays, but the tests will run instantly.

Comment: I don't want to simulate time. I want to simulate the connection. I want my app to run as if it had a real connection whilst i use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also looked for the solution and after reading the [intro to rx](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#ObservableTimer) made my self one:
There is an `Observable.Generate()` overload which I have used to make my own `ToObservable()` extension method, taking `TimeSpan` as period:

```
public static class MyEx {
    public static IObservable<T> ToObservable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, TimeSpan period) 
    {
        return Observable.Generate(
            enumerable.GetEnumerator(), 
            x => x.MoveNext(),
            x => x, 
            x => x.Current, 
            x => period);
    }
    public static IObservable<T> ToObservable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T,TimeSpan> getPeriod) 
    {
        return Observable.Generate(
            enumerable.GetEnumerator(), 
            x => x.MoveNext(),
            x => x, 
            x => x.Current, 
            x => getPeriod(x.Current));
    }
}
```

Already tested in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/Beta.aspx). Only concerning about what happens with the enumerator instance after the resulting observable is e.g. disposed. Any corrections appreciated.

Comment: This solution, as it is, will only work the very first time the returned IObservable is subscribed to. That's because the IEnumerator instance is reused, resulting in undefined behavior. Furthermore, it will never be disposed, possibly leaking.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Interval together with Zip to get the desired functionality:

```
var sequence = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                         .Zip(e.ToObservable(), (tick, index) => index)
```

Comment: Zip has an overload with takes in an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Is this dangerous with, for example infinite sequences. Would not zip try to buffer the infinite sequence and quickly blow the memory or is it smarter than this?

Comment: Yes Zip will try to buffer values until they are pushed with a value from the other sequence as a pair. So in this example it would buffer 1024 values and take 1024 seconds to complete.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need something to schedule notifying observers with each value taken from the Enumerable.
You can use the [recursive Schedule overload on an Rx scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211640%28v=vs.103%29.aspx#Y0).

```
Public Shared Function Schedule ( _
    scheduler As IScheduler, _
    dueTime As TimeSpan, _
    action As Action(Of Action(Of TimeSpan)) _
) As IDisposable
```

On each scheduled invocation, simply call `enumerator.MoveNext()`, and call `OnNext(enumerator.Current)`, and finally `OnCompleted` when `MoveNext()` returns false. This is pretty much the bare-bones way of doing it.

An alternative was to express your requirement is to restate it as "for a sequence, have a minimum interval between each value".

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12653764/802116). The test case resembles your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do this very simple approach:

```
dim e = Enumerable.Range(0, 1024)
dim o = e.ToObservable().Do(Sub (x) Thread.Sleep(1000))
```

When you subscribe to `o` the values take a second to be produced.

Comment: Every time a `Thread.Sleep` is executed inside an observer block, Jeffrey Van Gogh kills a kitten.

Comment: j/k I use this for testing all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that you are using Range to dumb down your question.

Do you want every value that the Enumerable pushes to be delayed by a second?

```
var e = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
var o = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                  .Zip(e, (_,i)=>i);
```

Or do you want only the last value of the Enumerable at each second to be pushed. i.e. reading from Enumerable that is evaluating as you enumerate it (perhaps some IO). In which case **CombineLatest** is more useful than **Zip**.

Or perhaps you just want to get a value every second, in which case just use the Observable.Interval method

```
var o = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

If you explain your problem space then the community will be able to better help you.

Lee

*Excuse the C# answer, but I dont know what the equivalent VB.NET code would be.