# Convert IEnumerable to IObservable with variable Period

Tags: c#, unit-testing, system.reactive

I am consuming 3-axis accelerometer data using Rx.  I need to set up some unit tests.  The data frames come in fast, with the median timespan between frames being 80ms, but on occasion it comes in at 120ms.  Also, it is never exactly 80ms, but hovers in that range.

So I have created a class that subscribes to the IObservable and records the dataframes sequentially in a .csv file.  One of the fields in the .csv file is the start time of the frame with the first frame having start time = 0.0.

Now I want to read that file and stream it again for the purpose of testing and development.  I want to use the StartTime field as the schedule for when I will fire any given Accelerometer frame when testing.

I looked over the answers in this question, [Scheduling a IEnumerable periodically with .NET reactive extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692244/scheduling-a-ienumerable-periodically-with-net-reactive-extensions)
but it seems only to address constant timespans.

**Question:**
Is there already a canonical and preferred way to schedule frame pushes at irregular (but known) intervals in the Rx framework, or should I just roll my own somehow?

Edit 2:
I am interested in something which could be as simple as:

```
IObservable<T> AsObservable(
   IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TimeSpan> getTimeDelta)
{
   var retVal = ColdObservableVaryingTime();
   foreach(var frame in source)
   {
       retVal.AddScheduled(getTimeDelta, frame);
   }
   return retVal;
}
```

Edit 1: what I call "frames" in this question, Rx documentation calls TState.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided by James Lucas is a good pointer in the right direction, but the answer that succeded is more involved.

After I populate my IEnumerable with values from the csv file, I have to populate an array of

```
Recorded<Notification<AccelerometerFrame_raw>>
```

I then pass the array as parameter to scheduler CreateColdAbservable.  After this has been accomplished, the cold observable is sitting there waiting to be started.  In my particular situation, the code looks like this:

```
private TestScheduler sched {get; set;}
public IObservable<AccelerometerFrame_raw> DataStream { get; protected set; }
ctor()
{
   DataStream = SetupDeviceStream();
}
  private IObservable<AccelerometerFrame_raw> SetupDeviceStream()
  {
     var framesArray = 
       new Recorded<Notification<AccelerometerFrame_raw>>[allFrames.Count+1];
     int i = 0;
     long timeStamp = 0;
     foreach(var item in allFrames)
     {
        timeStamp += (long) (item.TimeStampSeconds * 1000.0);
        framesArray[i] = new Recorded<Notification<AccelerometerFrame_raw>>(
           timeStamp, 
           Notification.CreateOnNext(item));
        i++;
     }
     framesArray[i] = new Recorded<Notification<AccelerometerFrame_raw>>(
           timeStamp + 10, 
           Notification.CreateOnCompleted<AccelerometerFrame_raw>());

     sched = new TestScheduler();
     var stream =sched.CreateColdObservable(framesArray);
     return stream;
  }
```

//// when I am ready to start the cold observable, I call

```
sched.Start();
```

Help on putting this all together comes from

(Phil Haak) http://haacked.com/archive/2014/03/10/master-time-with-reactive-extensions/

and
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229343(v=vs.103).aspx

It is also necessary to install another Nuget package:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/reactiveui-testing/

As Phil Haak says in the linked blog post, "Unfortunately, [TestScheduler] is a bit of a pain to use as-is which is why Paul Betts took it upon himself to write some useful TestScheduler extension methods"

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option for you. The `Observable.Generate` method is very powerful and it can be used to produce quite sophisticated sequences of values.

Here's how you could do it.

So, starting with a CSV file like this:

```
var csvLines = new []
{
    "A,0",
    "B,3",
    "C,4",
    "D,6",
};
```

(Which could be read like `var csvLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"...");`.)

You could then parse the lines:

```
var parsed =
(
    from line in csvLines
    let parts = line.Split(',')
    select new
    {
        item = parts[0],
        seconds = int.Parse(parts[1])
    }
).ToArray();
```

And then determine the seconds `offset` between each line in the CSV:

```
var data =
    parsed
        .Zip(parsed.Skip(1), (p0, p1) => new
        {
            p1.item,
            offset = p1.seconds - p0.seconds,
        })
        .ToArray();
```

Now you can create the observable:

```
var observable =
    Observable
        .Generate(
            0,
            n => n < data.Length,
            n => n + 1,
            n => data[n].item,
            n => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(data[n].offset))
        .StartWith(parsed[0].item);
```

When I ran through this code I got the correct timings from my source file.

---

I've updated my code given your class definition in the comments below:

```
IEnumerable<AccelerometerFrame_raw> frames = ...;

var data =
    frames
        .Zip(frames.Skip(1), (f0, f1) => new
        {
            f1,
            offset = f1.TimeStampSeconds - f0.TimeStampSeconds,
        })
        .ToArray();

IObservable<AccelerometerFrame_raw> observable =
    Observable
        .Generate(
            0,
            n => n < data.Length,
            n => n + 1,
            n => data[n].f1,
            n => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(data[n].offset))
        .StartWith(frames.First());
```

Comment: Thank you Enigmativity.  Your example looks nice for an array.  Do I have to convert my IEnumerable ToArray()?  I would rather use IEnumerable<T>  where T is a reference type.  So the first parameter would be null.  But the next two parameters, Condition and Iterate, would both call n.MoveNext(), wouldn't they?  So how can this be used with IEnumerable without going through typing to an Array?

Comment: Clarification: And two calls to MoveNext() per frame would result in skipping every other one and perhaps getting a nullReferenceException on collections with even .Length values.

Comment: @philologon - I'm not sure what you're asking. My `csvLines` happens to be an array, but when you read the file it will be an enumerable. I don't know what you mean by the first parameter will be `null` - what first parameter? I also don't understand what you mean by "Condition and Iterate"? What `.MoveNext()`? What "frame"? There won't be any issues with even length sequences. Can you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: I am refering to the parameter names in the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212066(v=vs.103).aspx .  Sorry for the ambiguity.  I thought it would be clear to you that 'condition' refers to the parameter named 'condition' and 'iterate' refers to the parameter named 'iterate'. Iterate is "the iteration step function" and 'condition' is "the condition to terminate generation".  But IEnumerables do not have indexers, so I am supposing the only way to use one with Generate is to pass the methods the IEnumerator uses to advance (MoveNext() ) and to indicate completion ...

Comment: ... to indicate completion, which is when .MoverNext() returns null.    Also, I mention the first parameter being null because a generic reference type would be null, not 0.

Comment: By "frame" I mean each T of the IObservable<T>.  I.e., the object that is sent in OnNext.  Like a frame of video.  So with .MoveNext() being called twice "per frame", the first .MoveNext would get frame[0] and the other .MoveNext (checking for completion) would cause the next frame (frame[1], etc.) to be accessed but not sent to OnNext.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want `data` to be an array?

Comment: Lazy Evaluation.  This is a minor point, which is why I was inquiring if there is a convenient way to use .Generate without it being an array.  If the answer is "well, no not really", that is fine.  Just asking.

Comment: While we have been talking I have attempted to make .Generate work with an array.  (My class is two vectors and a timestamp.)  It looks like Generate only works with arrays of value types or maybe even just arrays of ints.  In any case, as best as I can tell after trying to make it work in code, Generate does not seem to be a viable solution for my situation.  But I really do appreciate your help and your time.

Comment: @philologon - The array makes sense here for two reasons - one you're loading a file so it makes sense to read all in one go - and two that the generate method is using an index so an array is the best option. Now, generate will work fine on any array regardless if it is a value or reference type. What makes you think your class won't work? Can you post your data type?

Comment: public class AccelerometerFrame_raw
{ public Vector3D Acceleration { get; internal set; }
      public Vector3D RotationRate { get; internal set; }
      public long TimeStampTicks { get; internal set; }
      public Double TimeStampSeconds { get { return TimeStampTicks / ticksPerSecond; } }  }

Comment: What makes me think it wouldn't work?  It wouldn't compile.  For example, when I made an array of accelerometer frames, and in iterate: I put the lamba like so, n -> n++;, the compiler balked and told me there was no overloaded ++ for type accelerometer.

Comment: @philologon - Why did you put `n => n++`? My code hasn't got that.

Comment: Because outside of lambdas (that is, in most code we write) n++ is the same as n = n + 1.  I can now see how they would not be the same in lambdas.  But it is still a non-essential point.  No matter what I put, that lamba is Func<TState, TState> and TState for me is an accelerometer frame.  You don't increment accelerometer frames, which is what iterate: wants to do.  You move next, and Generate just will not do it the way an enumerable would.

Comment: @philologon - You do realize that `n++` is a post-increment and the value returned is the original `n`. You need to do `++n` to get pre-increment.

Comment: Thanks again for your very nice help.  When I copy/pasted your code into mine, it compiled without me needing to change it.  It runs and sends the first few frames.  But on about the 3rd or 4th frame it crashes.  I am still trying to track down the exception it is generating.  That is, I would, but I already have the working solution that I accepted.  So thanks for your help, but it is not time-efficient for me to pursue this any further since the other solution works without more debugging.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use the TestScheduler (get the Rx-Testing Nuget package). Using this class as your IScheduler implementation within your tests will allow you to schedule your sequence as the test scheduler allows you to create observable sequences by stating when each item should be pushed. You can then 'play' the scheduler or advance to a time etc and see what happened. Note that in this setting time is virtualised and for simplicity the TestScheduler deals in Ticks as its unit of time progression.

The Intro to RX site has a nice section on RX testing here: http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/16_TestingRx.html

Comment: Thank you, James.  I will investigate this.

Comment: James, I have looked over the link you provide, plus some other resources on TestScheduler.  There is a lot of material there, but does it have the answer to my question?  I'm not sure, and I will continue to study it.  But I have added a clarification to my original post to help people see what kind of solution I was hoping was available.  Can you explain if anything in TestScheduler can be used like my (above) sample code or similar?