# How to build a single scheduled Observable from an array with timestamps

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observable

I have some code which is slowly live streamed from an observable. I would like to simulate the live stream from the persisted objects and their time stamp via another observable.

I have been able to make something work using Observable.Return.Delay on the array and then merging in to a single observable. I get the feeling this isn't the correct approach and there is maybe a thread needed for every item, so the timing may fail once the thread pool is full.

```
var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);

var observable = data
    .Select((x, idx) => Observable.Return(x).Delay(DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(idx*3)))
    .Merge();
```

What is the best way to schedule static data?

Comment: Is this for testing purposes?

Comment: It's for replaying a Production environment in UAT.

Comment: You may want to use something like `.Concat` instead of `Merge` else with very large sets for `data` you may just flood the Scheduler. That would however only work if you had relative timestamps. You example however just uses generated `idx` which I assume isn't what you actually are doing (reading from a Log or and Event Stream instead)

Comment: Question regarding the question: "...and their timestamp" - Do you want to replay the data every 3 seconds (as your sample code shows) or do you want them to be replayed at the original rate?

Comment: `Delay` schedules notifications on an `IScheduler`, which will put them into a priority queue and emit them when time has come to do so. So no, not every item needs a thread. But creating observables of length 1 for every item indeed seems strange. See my answer for a solution that directly schedules the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of different answers to this one and I'm not entirely sure which is the best solution.

I have found a couple of fairly clean looking solutions...

```
public static IObservable<TSource> IntervalSeries<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> items, Func<TSource, TimeSpan> delayResolver)
{
    return items.Select(x => Observable.Return(x).DelaySubscription(delayResolver(x))).Concat();
}
```

---

```
public static IObservable<TSource> IntervalSeries<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> items, Func<TSource, TimeSpan> delayResolver)
{
    return items.Select(x => Observable.Empty<TSource>().Delay(delayResolver(x)).Concat(Observable.Return(x))).Concat();
}
```

Probably the best solution which feels like it uses a utility method designed for this and so is less likely to suffer from side effects is the Generate method which Daniel C. Weber [referred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42134652/1194731) to. Although I didn't quite grasp it until I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22863293/1194731) more detailed answer.

```
public static IObservable<TSource> IntervalSeries<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> items, Func<TSource, TimeSpan> delayResolver)
{
    return Observable.Generate(
        items.GetEnumerator(),
        x => x.MoveNext(),
        x => x,
        x => x.Current,
        x => delayResolver(x.Current));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an overload of `Generate` that takes exact `DateTimeOffset` values for when to emit an item. [Take a look](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229270(v=vs.103).aspx).

The signature looks complex but is quite straightforward. You should make sure that the timestamps you use are in ascending order since the timestamp-function is only evaluated when the preceding item has been emitted.

Where are you getting the timestamps from? You mentioned another observable. If you could enhance your example, I could try to produce some working code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would use the [Observable.Interval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229027(v=vs.103).aspx) method.  If using this for testing and needing to reuse it you can create an method to handle delaying the results.

```
static IObservable<TSource> DelayObservable<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, TimeSpan delay)
{
    var observableSource = source.ToObservable();

    // Use start with to fire one off right away
    var interval = Observable.Interval(delay).StartWith(0);

    // Zip so when the enumerable is done interval is auto unsubscribed
    return interval.Zip(observableSource, (d, S) => S);
}
```

Then can call it like

```
var observable = DelayObservable(Enumerable.Range(1, 10), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
```

Comment: I have a different time associated with each item in the array and would need a specific delay per item in the array. Sorry my example code didn't make this clear. I do like the idea of zipping the two observables though.

Comment: FYI `var interval = Observable.Interval(delay).StartWith(0);` could be written as `var interval = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, delay);`

Comment: @KrisG I ran your code and it's only putting 3 seconds between each one.  Are you looking for 3 seconds, then 6 seconds then 9 second delays between each output?

Answer (score 0):

There's a handy class as part of the Rx package you can use: `Timestamped`. By all means though, you don't have to. Here's an example:

```
var timestampedObjects = Enumerable.Range(0, 5)
    .Select(i => Timestamped.Create(i, DateTimeOffset.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i*i)))
    .ToList();

var observable = timestampedObjects.ToObservable()
    .SelectMany(t => Observable.Timer(t.Timestamp).Take(1).Select(_ => t.Value));

observable.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine($"{DateTimeOffset.Now}: {i}"));
```

This is almost identical to your solution except subbing out `Delay` for `Timer`. `Delay` is intended to preserve the time-gaps between elements for a complete observable, but time-shift everything. `Timer` is meant for absolute scheduling a single item.

`Select` followed by `Merge` is equivalent to `SelectMany`.

Your solution should work, and I wouldn't worry about threading issues, Rx is fairly efficient at scheduling/combining thread resources.

The other alternative is the package `Microsoft.Reactive.Testing`, which allows you to schedule things in virtual time, hours or even years apart, yet run them instantly. It's great for unit testing, somewhat cumbersome for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Play` operator like this and feed it with your data - possibly with time-shifted (into the future) items. I chose to use a `Notification<T>`, so it will also support testing for completion and error.

```
public static IObservable<T> Play<T>(this IEnumerable<Timestamped<Notification<T>>> source, IScheduler scheduler = null)
{
    if (scheduler == null) scheduler = Scheduler.Default;

    return Observable.Create<T>(observer => new CompositeDisposable(source
        .Where(tn => tn.Timestamp > scheduler.Now)
        .Select(tn => scheduler.Schedule(tn.Timestamp, () => tn.Value.Accept(observer)))));
}
```

Test:

```
var events = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
    .Select(i => Timestamped.Create(i, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(3 * i)))
    .ToList();
var sch = new TestScheduler();
var testee = events
    .Select(e => Timestamped.Create(Notification.CreateOnNext(e.Value), e.Timestamp))
    .Play(sch);
var result = new List<Timestamped<int>>();
using (testee.Timestamp(sch).Subscribe(i => result.Add(i)))
    sch.Start();
Assert.True(result.SequenceEqual(events));
```