# How to use Rx to deliver events on a schedule?

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.reactive

I'm using Reactive Extensions for C#. I want several threads to enqueue items on a ConcurrentQueue. Then I want to Subscribe to that queue, but only get 1 element every 1 second. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20645110/124800) almost works, but not when I add more elements to the queue.

Given a queue of ints: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]. I want Subscribe(Console.WriteLine) to print a value every second. I want to add more ints from another thread onto the queue while Rx is printing these numbers out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pace an input stream to output no faster than at a rate described by a `Timespan` interval, use this:

```
var paced = input.Select(i => Observable.Empty<T>()
                                        .Delay(interval)
                                        .StartWith(i)).Concat();
```

See [here](http://www.zerobugbuild.com/?p=323) for an explanation. Here's an example implementation tailored to a concurrent queue that dequeues quickly. Note that using the `ToObservable` extension of `IEnumerable<T>` to convert `ConcurrentQueue<T>` to an observable directly would be a mistake, because sadly this observable completes as soon as the queue is empty. It's jolly annoying that - at least as far as I can see - there's no asynchronous dequeue on a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` and so I had to introduce a polling mechanism. Other abstractions (e.g. `BlockingCollection<T>`) may serve you better!

```
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<T> Pace<T>(this ConcurrentQueue<T> queue,
                                         TimeSpan interval)
    {
        var source = Observable.Create<T>(async (o, ct) => {

            while(!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                T next; 
                while(queue.TryDequeue(out next))
                    o.OnNext(next);

                // You might want to use some arbitrary shorter interval here
                // to allow the stream to resume after a long delay in source
                // events more promptly    
                await Task.Delay(interval, ct);
            }   

            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        });

        // this does the pacing
        return source.Select(i => Observable.Empty<T>()
                     .Delay(interval)
                     .StartWith(i)).Concat()
                     .Publish().RefCount(); // to allow multiple subscribers    
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();

    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    queue.Pace(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Subscribe(
            x => Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + ": x" + x),
            e => Console.WriteLine(e.Message),
            () => Console.WriteLine("Done"));

    stopwatch.Start();
    queue.Enqueue(1);
    queue.Enqueue(2);
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    queue.Enqueue(3);
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    queue.Enqueue(4);
    queue.Enqueue(5);
    queue.Enqueue(6);

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: This solution will misbehave with multiple subscription. Race condition.

Comment: Yes it will, quite right - I should have pointed that out. Whilst still open to abuse to multiple calls to Pace, I have added `Publish().RefCount()` to afford the proper protection.

Comment: It works! Thanks. Can this be generalized to extend Observables, rather than specifically on ConcurrentQueue?

Comment: Of course,  the generalised version is the first code snippet - `input` is any `IObservable<T>`

Answer (score 1):

May be you will satisfied with one of [Observable.Buffer](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html#Buffer) overload. But consider not to use buffering with long running subsriptions because buffered elements can stress your RAM.

You can also build you own extension method with any desired behavior using [Observable.Generate](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#ObservableGenerate)

```
void Main()
{
    var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
    queue.Enqueue(1);
    queue.Enqueue(2);
    queue.Enqueue(3);
    queue.Enqueue(4);
    queue.ObserveEach(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).DumpLive("queue");
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static class Ex {
    public static IObservable<T> ObserveConcurrentQueue<T>(this ConcurrentQueue<T> queue, TimeSpan period) 
    {
        return Observable
            .Generate(
                queue, 
                x => true,
                x => x, 
                x => x.DequeueOrDefault(), 
                x => period)
            .Where(x => !x.Equals(default(T)));
    }

    public static T DequeueOrDefault<T>(this ConcurrentQueue<T> queue)
    {
        T result;
        if (queue.TryDequeue(out result))
            return result;
        else
            return default(T);
    }
}
```

Comment: Buffer works if my inputs arrive at less than the Buffer's timespan. If my inputs come faster, then I'll get a batch of items all at once. That's not the desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks! This works. When I tested with T=int, the Where clause dropped all 0s.